# Fundamentally, what is direction?

Tags: spacetime, geometry

What physical properties does direction exhibit when applied on a physical on an object.

---

This maybe leaning into mathematics/philosophy but my question is what is direction? It is defined by wikipedia as: Direction is the information vested in the relative position of a destination (or target) point with respect to a starting point, absent the distance information. I have to some degree known that all my life. But lately I thought what IS direction if you know what I mean. What does direction measure fundamentally? I don't have advanced knowledge of physics but you get base units, why is direction not one or rather what kind of unit is direction? (I don't mean it basically, I just can't think how to put it into advanced terms) I might be overthinking it.. lol and I might look stupid but do you know what I mean?? Maybe I should head to the philosophy section. I put a large emphasis on (WHAT *IS* DIRECTION) in a deep intellectual and mathematical/physical way (do you get my drift?). Are there any important equations that define direction in mathematics and physics?. Are there any notable facts about direction (is there anything notable relating to direction when it comes to black holes, (for example at the centre))? You get direction in space and you also get direction in time, in what ways do these types of direction vary and are they or have been given different units of measurement. Do particles exhibit physical properties that define their direction (please try to understand I mean in a complex way not in ways like (particle A that has direction exhibit properties such as it moves from 0,1 to 7,0)). I would appreciate it a lot if you could expand on what I have asked and show some flare (what effects that are exhibited in quantum mechanics that relate to direction and the changes of what direction is in each nth direction with theory such as string theory). Maybe this is a simple concept and I will get embarrassed and get a very short answer but it just one of those questions that popped up in my head and seemed intriguing. Are there any cases that a physical particle or object does not exhibit direction (maybe it's in the 0 dimension... I don't have advanced knowledge).

I posted this question and I feel very nervous that I look very stupid please can someone confirm? I've been doing alot of programming so I can see where them mixup of concepts might come in.

Answer (score 0):

This questions seems vague, open to interpretation and not belonging on the site.

To play Devil's advocate though: the way I see it, "Direction" is an artifact of a reference frame, the 'same point' in space could be viewed as many different distances from many different reference frames, in many different directions.

I would then go on to define direction as just the bearing of a vector describing some quantity [such as displacement, velocity or momentum etc] in a respective reference frame.

Comment: So bit of a stupid question would you say or is there more to it?

Comment: I can't personally see there being one, I feel like if you want a more philosophical definition ask on the stackexchange of Philosophy?

Comment: How should I reformat the question?

Comment: Perhaps ask it [here](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Hm when I asked myself what is direction and here it was not strictly in an intellectual sense but an emotional one as well, but yes maybe this is the wrong medium or wrong site department.

Answer (score -1):

Direction is the information for the relative position between two objects without the distance information. One object must be considered the source or starting point and the other the target or destination. You can store this information mathematically for spatial direction by using a unit vector or direction vector.  In 3D this would be a specific point[x,y,z] on sphere with length/radius 1.

Comment: I don't quite know the definition of information but from what I gather direction is just an abstract concept in mild terms?